# Ink Free font in latex?

Tags: fonts

Is the Ink Free font available in Latex? I've tried to find the solution by google while found no connection between ink free font and latex. Any information will be helpful, thanks.

Comment: What's an 'ink free' font?

Comment: @JosephWright it's a name not a description:-)

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your posting and changed "ink-free" to "Ink Free". Feel free to revert if you think I missed something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have the font installed (from Windows or Office or you have bought it) then as with any system font, it is usable with xelatex or lualatex directly.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Ink Free}

\begin{document}

One two three four.

\end{document}
```

(this using lualatex)